# Difference between output of Client.class.getName() and Classname.class in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

What is the difference between output of following two methods in log4j. I am getting same output using both the methods. First method is returning string value and second method is returning class.

First Method:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Abc { 
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName())
}
```

Second Method:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Abc { 
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Abc.class)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of `Logger.getLogger`, one that takes a `Class` and one that takes an arbitrary string. The call

```
Logger.getLogger(Something.class)
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
Logger.getLogger(Something.class.getName())
```

and will return the logger whose name matches the fully-qualified name of the class.